# How can remove this gcc flags from linker flags in cmake?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake, linker

I made simple kernel for studying purposes. I cange MakeFile to CMakeLists.txt to automatically genreate my kernel form sources. But I encounter this relocation error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/x86_64-kernel.bin.dir/src/arch/x86_64/multiboot2_boot32.asm.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.boot.32' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
```

To solve this I think I have to remove -fno-pie in linker flags. By checking log of gcc with make VERBOSE=1, I can found that there is CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS at my linker flags.

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable x86_64-kernel.bin
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/x86_64-kernel.bin.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/gcc   -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=large -mno-sse -ffreestanding -nostdlib -fno-pie -fno-pic  -rdynamic -n -T /home/ahn9807/study/AOS/src/arch/x86_64/linker.ld CMakeFiles/x86_64-kernel.bin.dir/src/arch/x86_64/kernel_entry.cpp.o CMakeFiles/x86_64-kernel.bin.dir/src/arch/x86_64/multiboot2_boot32.asm.o CMakeFiles/x86_64-kernel.bin.dir/src/arch/x86_64/multiboot2_boot64.asm.o CMakeFiles/x86_64-kernel.bin.dir/src/arch/x86_64/multiboot2_header.asm.o  -o x86_64-kernel.bin 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/x86_64-kernel.bin.dir/src/arch/x86_64/multiboot2_boot32.asm.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.boot.32' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
```

How can I remove this CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in my LINKER_FLAGS? Why camke automatically insert this useless options for my MakeFile? Is there any other way to bypass this error messages? I hope your answers...
And this is my CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.17)

project(kernell)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR 1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDAED 17)

set(KERNEL_BIN "x86_64-kernel.bin")

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(LINKER_SCRIPT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/arch/x86_64/linker.ld)
set(GRUB_CFG ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/arch/x86_64/grub.cfg)

set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT "elf64")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=large -mno-sse -ffreestanding -nostdlib -fno-pie -fno-pic")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=large -mno-sse -ffreestanding -nostdlib -fno-pie -fno-pic")
set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "{CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS} -felf64")

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++")
set(CMAKE_LINKER "/usr/bin/ld")

enable_language(ASM_NASM)

include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
)

add_executable(
    ${KERNEL_BIN}

    # Header files
    include/arch/x86_64/kernel_entry.h
    include/arch/x86_64/vga_text.h
    include/arch/x86_64/multiboot2.h

    # Source files
    src/arch/x86_64/kernel_entry.cpp
    src/arch/x86_64/multiboot2_boot32.asm
    src/arch/x86_64/multiboot2_boot64.asm
    src/arch/x86_64/multiboot2_header.asm
)

set_target_properties(${KERNEL_BIN} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-n -T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}")

add_custom_command(TARGET ${KERNEL_BIN} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND mkdir -p ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/isofiles/boot/grub
    COMMAND cp ${KERNEL_BIN} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/isofiles/boot/${KERNEL_BIN}
    COMMAND cp ${GRUB_CFG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/isofiles/boot/grub
    COMMAND grub-mkrescue -o kernel.iso ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/isofiles
    COMMAND rm -r ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build/
)
```

Comment: What do you find when you search for `-fno-pie` in the CMakeLists.txt file? With that is it not obvious what needs to be done?

Comment: I put -fno-pie option to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and CMAKE_C_FLAGS. I want to generate object files from these flags and linking them with only -n -T linker.ld. But cmake tries to linking my files with gcc and CMAKE_C*_FLAGS. I cannot understand why and how to fix relocation error produced by -f no-pie in linking stage.

Comment: More sepcfically, I cannot understand why cmake tries to linking my object files with gcc and gcc options. Despite that I told cmake to linking *.o with /usr/lib/ld and -n -T *.ld.

Comment: Why do you need `-fno-pie`?

Comment: Because I build kernel. In my kernel, kernel doesn't need PIE and PIC. Also this problem is oringinate from linker tries to link my kernel with all the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS with linking stages... I think at least..

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE.html#variable:CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE

Comment: It doesn't works...  But Thanks for your comment!

Comment: https://xmake.io/ ... if it's not too late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figure out how to remove useless linker argument from cmake. CMAKE uses compiler as an default linker. In my case, gcc is default linker because I build my source code with gcc. The important fact is that cmake **also berings CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS with gcc in linking stage**. So we have to use custom linker as like this to avoid cmake linking our oject files with default compiler linker.

```
set(CMAKE_LINKER "/usr/bin/ld")
set(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS "-n -T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_LINKER> ${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS} <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
```

In this way, we can automatically generate executable with custom linker.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I will add that we should use CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE instead if the project is C only